# did anybody use ACR1222L android library?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I am writing an app which will be run in tablets. The tablet will be connected to ACR1222L NFC reader.

I am using their android library to interact with the reader. I can detect the USB reader and also can read the readers name.
BUT i am struggling to read data from NFC tag. In fact I have no clue where to start, which classes/methods to use.

Is there anyone who already worked with ACR1222L and its android library?

Some guidelines, sample code, tutorial would save my life.

**EDIT:**

Well, I got little smarter now, I can read the UID. this is how to do it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
............... your code
mReader = new Reader(mManager);
    mReader.setOnStateChangeListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChange(int slotNum, int prevState, int currState) {
        //This command is for the card UID
            byte[] command = {(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x00};
         byte[] response = new byte[300];
         int responseLength;
          if (currState == Reader.CARD_PRESENT) {
 try {
                    mReader.power(slotNum,Reader.CARD_WARM_RESET);
                    mReader.setProtocol(slotNum, Reader.PROTOCOL_T0|     Reader.PROTOCOL_T1);
                    responseLength=mReader.transmit(slotNum,command,     command.length, response,response.length);

 //Here i have the card UID if i send the proper command
                    responsedata=NfcUtils.convertBinToASCII(response);

          }             

 }
}
```

BUT I am still struggling to read the payload from the tag. I have also look into nfctools library. But I don't know where to start. Would be great if anyone guide my through the library.

Comment: Did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: yes I did at that time but only for some specific tag. But I can not help you now since it's been more than a year and i also dont have the code with me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible - and quite the same as working with the ACR 122 as the API is almost identical.

I've developed  a (commmercially available) [library](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api) which probably does most of what you're looking into, or can serve as a starting point for your own implementation.